# Is it a verb or a noun?

Tags: verbs, nouns

I'm not sure if this is going to be a fruitful question or not, but what is the word *riposte* in the following sentence being referenced as, a verb or a noun?

> I like your riposte.

Is the sentence saying *it likes the action of "riposting" you did*, or *the literal riposte you did, it likes.*

Or maybe there is something different that I'm not considering? Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: If it were the action, as you yourself mention, the author of the sentence would have used _riposting_, not _riposte_.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you, Fev :)

Answer (score 1):

"Riposte" is modified by the personal pronoun "your". The only verb form that is commonly modified by a personal pronoun is a gerund<sup>1</sup>; in this case, that would be "riposting" (as fev has noted in a comment). Therefore, "riposte" in this sentence would normally be construed not as a verb but as a noun.

<sup>1</sup>As far as I'm aware, the only other verb form that is commonly modified "adjectivally" is a full infinitive. (For example: "To err is human.")